# Estimating lambda parameter

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I have random variable with exponential distribution. I am to find parameter Lambda. All i know is

$$\sum_{1}^{20}X_i^{2} = 30$$

I know i can solve this using moment method. Howeve , i fail to see the neccessarry steps in order to find

$$1/\lambda^{2} = 1/n-1 * \sum_{1}^{20} ( X_i - X_n ) ^{2}$$

I know i can expand right side to

$$\sum_{1}^{20} X_i^{2} - \sum_{1}^{2}2X_iX_n + \sum_{1}^{20}X_n^{2}$$

But thats where i am stuck. How to proceed with this calculation to find lambda?

All i see is that i can subtitute $\sum_{1}^{20}  X_i^{2}$ with 30.

Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe this is it: Let $\mu = E(X_i) = 1/\lambda.$ Then $\mu^2 = \sigma^2 = Var(X) = E(X^2) - \mu^2,$ so $E(X^2) = 2\mu^2$ and $\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i^2$ estimates $E(X^2).$

Answer (score 0):

*Comment continued:*  Just to illustrate the suggestion. (Not a proof.) 
If this makes sense to you, then you can fill in the analytic details.
Suppose $n=20,$ $\mu=\sqrt{3},$ $\mu^2 = 3.$ Then let's see
what happens with a million random samples of size 20 from an exponential
distribution with mean $\mu.$ Denote $Q = \frac 1n\sum_i X_i^2.$ (Computation using R statistical software.)

```
m = 10^6;  n = 20;  mu = sqrt(3);  lam=1/mu;  x = rexp(m*n, lam)
MAT=matrix(x, nrow=m)       # m x n matrix, each row a sample of 20
a = rowMeans(MAT);  mean(a)
## 1.731704                 # aprx E(X_i) = sqrt(3)
q = rowMeans(MAT^2);  mean(q)
## 5.996244                 # aprx E(Q) = 6
```